# Best way to put downloaded data into a dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Here is my data after being cleaned up:

```
| 3.9|JG0058|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384721......|W0982403......|C...|A 295
| 3.3|JG0713|2 .|29/VERT ANG|N384357.45928|W0982552.48655|....|ASTRO STAKE TEMPORARY
| 1.4|JG0054|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384459......|W0982059......|C...|B 295
| 4.4|JG0059|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384749......|W0982403......|B...|BB 190
| 1.5|JG0055|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384530......|W0982142......|B...|BLACK WOLF
| 2.0|JG0700|3 3|29/LEVELING|N384358.55373|W0982006.77896|....|BLACK WOLF
| 2.6|JG0052|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384438......|W0981921......|D...|C 295
| 2.3|JG0053|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384446......|W0981949......|B...|CC 190
| 4.6|JG0050|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384427......|W0981706......|C...|D 295
| 3.6|JG0051|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384430......|W0981817......|B...|DD 190
| 3.3|JG0712|1 .|29/VERT ANG|N384356.81442|W0982552.34585|....|JANDA
| 4.6|JG0711|2 .|29/SCALED..|N384053.85600|W0982456.07875|....|PROGRESS
| 4.9|JG0009|. 2|88/ADJUSTED|N384240......|W0981712......|C...|S 197
| 2.0|JG0056|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384555......|W0982251......|C...|Y 294
| 2.9|JG0057|. 1|88/ADJUSTED|N384636......|W0982335......|C...|Z 294
```

I would like to put individual lines into a dictionary with the following keys and types:

```
[@"blank",@"Dist", @"PID", @"Horiz", @"Vert", @"Vert_Source", @"Latitude", @"Longitude", @"Stability", @"Designation", nil];

[[NSString string],float, int, int,int, [NSString string], double, double, [NSString string], [NSString string], nil];
```

I cannot seem to figure out the best way to do it and I am banging my head against the wall with all of the options.  Please help if you can.  Perhaps a code snippet for reading the string into a dictionary or array.  By the way the data currently sits as a single string in a mutable array.  My intent is to then use this data to populate cells and ultimately map the locations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Searching for the data is generally 1 to 2 seconds and there would never be no more than say, 30 lines.

There is 8 items per line including a blank that I need that starts each line. Every other key is separated by the | except for the horizon/vert which are separated by nothing but indicated by a letters through d or a period.  That column begins at the third |.  I wish the website data was consistent but at least the index numbers don't change across the rows.

Comment: How many items per line do you have: 8 or 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate each string like this:

```
NSArray *values = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Then you can create the dictionary for that string like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
```

Where keys is an array defined like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blank",@"Dist", @"PID", @"Horiz", @"Vert", @"Vert_Source", @"Latitude", @"Longitude", @"Stability", @"Designation", nil];
```

So your code will look like this:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blank",@"Dist", @"PID", @"Horiz", @"Vert", @"Vert_Source", @"Latitude", @"Longitude", @"Stability", @"Designation", nil];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
    NSArray *values = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this assuming your data is an `NSString`:

```
NSArray *array = [data componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
```

Then loop through the data and place it inside a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
    blank = [components objectAtIndex:0];
    dist = [components objectAtIndex:1];
    PID = [components objectAtIndex:2];
    horiz = [components objectAtIndex:3];
        //...
```

Separate each by the |, then if you are interested using parts of the arrays you can set it up like that. If you rather not use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one dictionary to represent such a 'record' - (key,value) pairs - and put n such records in an array representing your 'table'. componentsSeparatedByString:@"|" breaks this into individual fields - suitable to load a record (dictionary) and populate the array.